# Why this won't be fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to make a button to start playing video on player.
Player is showing up and works fine if I press "Playing"  on control bar.
But My `a href link` to start playing won't work.
`play()` won't be fired. why?

```
<script>
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
      ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    }

    function play() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.playVideo();
  }
}
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
  <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/P5_GlAOCHyE?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", 
                       "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

  </script>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="play();">Play</a>
```

Comment: check your browser console for any errors

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ahhh,, This is ridiculous. It worked on FireFox but on Safari. Why it doesn't support Mac???

Comment: @SalmanA why is that not required? how will the function `onYouTubePlayerReady` gets called then? <i>note: I haven't used the `swfobject` library before</i>

Comment: @Arun: YouTube API checks for this function specifically and fires it if it is present.

Comment: @SalmanA Could you show me an example with code?

Comment: @MKK, does it work after you wait for few seconds ?

Comment: @Jashwant No it won't

Answer (score 0):

Talking to Flash objects can be difficult. Here's the code I use to send messages:

```
function runFlashFunction( flashName, funcName ) {
    var
    od = document[flashName],
    ow = window[flashName];
    // flash isn't happy with o=func;o(); syntax
    try {
        if( od && !!(od[funcName]) ) {
            return document[flashName][funcName]( );
        }
        if( ow && !!(ow[funcName]) ) {
            return window[flashName][funcName]( );
        }
        if( ow && ow.length && !!(ow[0]) && !!(ow[0][funcName]) ) {
            return window[flashName][0][funcName]( );
        }
        return void 0;
    } catch( ex ) {
        return void 0;
    }
}
```

Why all that? because some browsers use different ways to access the flash content. The last one probably isn't needed, but I include it to be sure.

Also your link uses a style which isn't recommended. This is better:

```
<a href="#" onclick="play();return false">Play</a>
```

Or even better: assign the callback in the JavaScript, not the HTML:

```
$(function(){
    $('#playLink').click(function(){ // name the link playLink (or whatever)
        play();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. But your explanation doesn't talk about what else codes needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use a global variable

```
var ytplayer = null;
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
   ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
}

function play() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.playVideo();
  }
}
```